# What's different when implementing Flex authentication/authorization in a clustered environment?

Tags: java, apache-flex, security, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing

Are there any differences implementing Flex application security in a clustered Java environment (such as Oracle Application Server/OC4J or a JBoss cluster) vs a single application server environment? (And/or does it depend on the specific environment software?)

What considerations are there in a situation where you need to authenticate with LDAP (AD) and store user access information in a database (ex. USER table containing username + permissions/roles info)?

Are sessions shared across nodes with no issues? Any differences between Blaze DS and Granite DS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Blaze DS is a pain when it comes to clustering full stop. LCDS isn't much better, but it at least has more support for clustering (with the downside of being ridiculously expensive).

The problem is the JSESSIONID which the instance uses to identify the Flex client that's making the call. The associated Flex Session object isn't shared in the cluster by default, and IIRC, BlazeDS doesn't have any option for sharing, while LCDS has limited options... Sticky Sessions or port broadcasting.

I can't speak for any of the Open Source options, but clustering support is usually the purview of paid-for solutions...

Comment: So what are you saying? Flex sessions aren't shared at all, so Flex 'data services' aren't compatible with clustered environments out of the box? I'm thinking a good solution would be using Apache Shiro, which basically takes container based sessions out of the picture and doesn't care what type of "client" you have.

Comment: I've never managed it with BlazeDS, I'm not sure its actually possible. LCDS its doable but you have to make some compromises with your clustering setup. GraniteDS, et al, I have no idea.

Comment: It's rather scary that there seems to be little anyone has to say about this topic in the Flex/Java community, anywhere. This response is the first real one I've ever seen on the topic, so kudos for that, but I do wish there was some more info out there on the subject.